# Some icons on desktop are not visible on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, display, icons

I use Lenovo G50-45 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I usually use it with second display. It happens that most of desktop icons are not visible. I have many icons (say 20) and I can see only 'Trash' one pdf document and one folder with second display.
After removing second display and right clicking 'organize desktop by name' I can see 6 icons, but it is only small part of the whole number.

What to do to see all desktop icons? [image: what I see now on desktop]

(In some situations (e.g. another display) I can see all icons, I do not exactly know, at which situation it changed)

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're asking about.  Screenshots and/or photos showing the actual issue you're having will help us to understand what exactly you're seeing and help us to better assist you.

Comment: I have a solution, but cannot enter 'answer'. The problem was I recently had changed in 'Language Support' my native language to English. The old (czech) desktop with all the icons was not used, but in English desktop there were just 6 icons. So solution is just to copy (or move) from old desktop (named Plocha) to new one (called Desktop) and all icons are visible.

Comment: The question is open again so you can post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I recently had changed in 'Language Support' my native language to English. The old (czech) desktop with all the icons was not used, but in English desktop there were just 6 icons, which I see. So solution is just to copy (or move) from old desktop (named Plocha) to new one (called Desktop) and all icons are visible, now.